# Starting with android game programming r android basics ?

Tags: android

Hi I actually started android game programming  from the past 3 days and suddenly I have a dilemma wether to read the android basics completely and then continue with game programming . What shall I do now ! Continue with game programming r start with the basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It honestly depends on whether you want to practice Android application programming through making a game, or if you want to make a game that works on Android as well. For the first, Android basics. For the second, check out LibGDX and check up on actual *game programming basics*, because even the simplest game is more complex than it looks.

My favorite libGDX tutorial: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/09/19/LibGDX-Tutorial-1-Creating-an-initial-project.aspx